# PropertyChangedEventHandler not firing asynchronically

Tags: c#, wpf

I've implemented this property to hide and show an element:

```
private bool isWorking = false;

public bool IsWorking {
    get {
        return this.isWorking;
    }

    set {
        this.isWorking = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsWorking");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

But when i change the property, even if the method is async, it's changing in a sync way.

Can you explain me how to solve the issue? I tried to move a dispatcher event inside the property changed or the code, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Did you probably want to set `IsAsync` on the Binding? Otherwise it's unclear what exactly is supposed to work asynchronously.

Comment: I change the property inside a click method. By adding IsAsync now the changing is showing, but "later"

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but "later" seems to be part of the definition of "asynchronous". Please clarify your problem.

Comment: I would like to see the GUI updated when i change the binded property, but it's changing only at the end of the method, how can I solve the problem? Every answer i found, didn't work

Comment: Which method? You haven't shown any.

Comment: I can't post the code of it for legal issues,  anyway it's the callback of a click event on a datagrid. When i start the method, i set IsWorking to true and when i end, I set IsWorking to false again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to have an `async` Click event handler like this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.IsWorking = true;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
       // do some long processing
    });

    viewModel.IsWorking = false;
}
```

---

Or an async method in your view model

```
public async Task DoSomeProcessing()
{
    IsWorking = true;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
       // do some long processing
    });

    IsWorking = false;
}
```

that is called from an async Click handler like

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await viewModel.DoSomeProcessing();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked as i expected, i had a different thread for every task and a waitall, maybe it blocked the effects of my code ^^